# How to get nearby place id of a specific location with Google Places iOS sdk (Offline use case)

Tags: android, ios, location, google-places-api

I am trying to find a way to get a suggested list of place id using Google Places iOS sdk based on a specific location coordinates (long,lat). This is for an offline use case.

On iOS there is this API

```
  https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place
```

calling:

```
  [_placesClient currentPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlaceLikelihoodList *likelihoodList, NSError *error) {
```

will return suggested list of places id

The problem is that it returns only suggestion nearby current location. I'ved got an offline use case where a photo is taken sometime ago in a different location and would like it to tag to that location and not the current location.

Is it possible to use GMSCoordinateBounds to set the coordinates ? if so how ? 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds

This question also applicable to android. For web there is a way to this.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#PlaceSearchRequests
are we supposed to switch to webservices ? Thats really crap if we have to do it all over. Please do offer a real way to solve this.

Thank you so much.